# How to separate HTML elements which are in the same type of tag, but in different types using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`.find()` method of JQuery can be used to find a element tag in a HTML file. But how can I differentiate two tags of same type. As an example

```
new.find('input')
```

finds input tags. But how can I differentiate tags in a following kind of scenario.

```
new.find('input').attr('id', 'name'+ number);
```

In this case all input tags get affected. If I have two input tags, both of them get the same id. (This is a part of a code which is used to generate and assign ids dynamically.)

I have `<input type="text"/>` and `<input type="number" />` 
I need to assign ids to these two elements separately. How can I do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 3):

first never ever use 'new' as a variable, it is a special word in js !
then you can use selector attribute :

```
'input[attrName="attrValue"]'
```

for the part

> I have  and  I need to
>   assign ids to these two elements separately. How can I do it?

```
$('input').each(function(e){
  switch($(e).attr('type').toLowerCase()){
    case 'text' : e.id = 'whatever'; break;
    case 'number' : e.id = 'whateverelse'; break;
    //...
  }
});
```

Comment: I am doing this inside a script. This is how I found and assigned id to label tag. `cloned.find('label').attr('id', 'PayLbl' + noOfDivs);`. There was no problem since it has only one label tag. But in this case I have two input tags.

Comment: so parse each input, check the type, and set the id, see my edit

Comment: @disule has the answer

Comment: what happens if I have two input tags of same type then?

Comment: then you have to re formulate you question, then you have to use a selector more specific of course !

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find an element with type attribute, you can do it as:

```
 $("input[type='text']")
```

for multiple input of type='text', you shoud use each() as:

```
 $("input[type='text']").each(function(){

 });
```

here is example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/3ffkwv8e/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use new as a variable.

Also, you could use an **if statement**, or case, but probably you should use the selector attribute like this:

```
input[type="text"].attr("id", "theText");
input[type="number"].attr("id", "theNumber");
```